# How to make this 'div box' for firefox?

Tags: html

For some kind of menu I would like a box of 300 pixels width, with the items in it aligned to the right.  I came up with the following code which works just fine in IE and Chrome, but not in FF :

```
<div style="width:300px;" align="left">
    <div align="right">
        <img  src="images/item1.png">     <br/>
        <img  src="images/item2.png">     <br/>
        <img  src="images/item3.png">     <br/>
        <img  src="images/item4.png">     <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE : In FF, the images are on the right side of the screen, in stead of aligned right at 300px from the left.

UPDATE 2 : The solution appeared to be text-align...

Comment: Try setting the alignment on the images? <img  src="images/item1.png" align="right"> ?

Comment: The box is left aligned, the items in it are aligned right (see the inner div).  I could have dropped the outer div, and it would align left automatically, but I thought it would be more clear like this.

Comment: Don't use align="left" it is deprecated use styles instead

Comment: See my answer .I tested in FF.It seemed to be width= was not recognised by FF but IE by default recognises crap...When fixed to : it fixed itself on FF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after a lot of trying out things, I found it myself : text-align does the trick
(although it's aligning images here)

```
  <div style="width:300px; text-align:right;">
    <img  src="images/item1.png">     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item2.png">     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item3.png">     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item4.png">     <br/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
   <div style="width: 300px;">
     <div style="float: right;">
       <img src='images/item1.png' />
     </div>
    </div>
```

Oh and also, don't use HTML align parameters, use style.

Comment: can you post image what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
<div style="width=300px;">
<div style="float: right">
    <img  src="images/item1.png">     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item2.png">     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item3.png">     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item4.png">     <br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this width : not width =

```
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div style="float: right">
        <img src="images/item1.png">
        <br />
        <img src="images/item2.png">
        <br />
        <img src="images/item3.png">
        <br />
        <img src="images/item4.png">
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, not the problem, now it's aligning left in ff

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:300px;">
<div style="float:right">
    <img  src="images/item1.png" alt="img"/>     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item1.png" alt="img"/>     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item1.png" alt="img"/>     <br/>
    <img  src="images/item1.png" alt="img"/>     <br/>
</div>
</div>
```